# Refresh tab regardless if I interact with the site - Chrome Plugin (Windows)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions

I'm looking for a way to refresh a tab every x minutes regardless if I click somewhere in the tab or not.

All of the extensions I tested before (Refresh Monkey, Easy Auto Refresh, Page Refresh) stop refreshing when I click on any link.

Is this even possible or do I need something else than an extension?

Comment: What about a javascript injection with something like GreaseMonkey?

Comment: I tried javascript bookmarklets but they get flushed after the page reloads too.

Comment: Please edit your question and include a list of the extensions (etc) you've already tried, or you're just going to get answers suggesting extensions you've already tried. :)  You should also include the OS in question.